# Twitter bootstrap & Highchart: horizontal scroll, responsive

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, responsive-design

Dear Elders of The Internet - 
I have created a headache for myself, and I hope you can help :-)

This is a two-part questions. I have a page with three panels, and want a horisontal slide. [For this I have created buttons, see live demo here.](http://barebente.com/tmp/NS-poc-2/testeri2.html)

**1. Horizontal slide, responsive**
When clicking  top right button *"two right panes"* I want the page to show just that: the two right panes *only*. This is not a problem on large screens, but I cannot get it to work on slightly smaller (media queries and further responsiveness, I think I will be able to figure out).

Similarly; when clicking *"single left pane"* I would like it to stretch the third (far right) panel, and hide the two others.

Clearly, I want it to respond to a 100% viewport.

**2. Highchart**
I cannot get the Highchart chart to act accordingly depending on the top left buttons sliding. The highchart will adjust *if I resize the whole window*, but I cannot get it to adjust when sliding panels. For a demo of a chart that works, scroll down in third panel (this is "homemade" graphs).

I have attempted to illustrate the problem in the screenshots below.

(I have posted [another question relating to the same page,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058623/twitter-bootstrap-popover-scroll-in-separate-panels) if you should be so inclined to take a look).

I suspect it is pretty simple, but I cannot for the life of me see where I went wrong. Any hints would be much appreciated. All the best.

[image: sliding, view of "two right panels"]

[image: view of single right panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, good people, I kinda figured it out myself... for the possible benefit of others; my  solution was to set the width of the two first columns fixed (or rather; max-width), and thereby using calc to calculate the size of the third columns with minus the two fixed width divs.

```
  width: -webkit-calc(98% - 520px);
 width: calc(98% - 520px);
```

For the Highchart part of the question, much thanks to @Pawel for prompt answer. I haven´t entirely worked it out, as we are currently discussing whether using Highcharts or not is the way to go. If so, I guess I might be back with more questions later.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts will resize only when window is resized, if you want to resize chart use `chart.setSize(w,h)`, see [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize%28%29).